# sed, awk to copy paste pattern1 line into following pattern2 lines

Tags: awk, sed

I'm looking to copy -city- line to end of "all" following -business- lines

This:

```
-country-france
-city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-TotalEnergies
-business-AXA
-business-Carrefour
-business-Crédit Agricole
-business-Peugeot
-business-BNP Paribas

-country-india
-city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Reliance Industries Limited
-business-State Bank of India
-business-HDFC Bank
-business-ICICI Bank
-business-Tata Consultancy Services
-business-Larsen & Toubro

-country-japan
-city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Toyota Motor
-business-Mitsubishi UFJ Financial
-business-Softbank
-business-Nippon Telegraph & Tel
```

to this:

```
-country-france
-city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-TotalEnergies -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-AXA -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Carrefour -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Crédit Agricole -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Peugeot -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-BNP Paribas -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes

-country-india
-city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Reliance Industries Limited -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-State Bank of India -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-HDFC Bank -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-ICICI Bank -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Tata Consultancy Services -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Larsen & Toubro -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata

-country-japan
-city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Toyota Motor -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Mitsubishi UFJ Financial -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Softbank -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Nippon Telegraph & Tel -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
```

This I have used elsewhere doesn't work here as expected. Appreciate any help.

```
sed -i -r ":begin;$!N;s/^-city-(.*)\n-business-(.*)/-business-\2-city-\1\n-city-\1/;tbegin;P;D" input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` :

```
sed '/^-country/{p;d};/^-city/{h;p;d};/^$/!{G;s/\n/ /}' test_file
```

In a multiline commented fashion :

```
sed '
    /^-country/{p;d;}; # If found a country print and go to the next line
    /^-city/{h;p;d;};  # If found a city save the line, print and go to the next line
    /^$/!{G;s/\n/ /;}; # For any, non empty lines, get the one saved before and attach it to the current line.
' file
```

---

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^-city/{h = $0} NF && !/^-(country|city)/ {$0 = $0 " " h} 1' test
```

Basically the same of the `sed` above.

When found a line starting with `-city` save it.

Then for each, non empty, lines which is not a `-country` or a `-city` line itself, print the current line joined to the one saved before.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^-city/h;/^-business/G;s/\n/ /' input_file
-country-france
-city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-TotalEnergies -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-AXA -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Carrefour -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Crédit Agricole -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Peugeot -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-BNP Paribas -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes

-country-india
-city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Reliance Industries Limited -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-State Bank of India -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-HDFC Bank -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-ICICI Bank -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Tata Consultancy Services -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Larsen & Toubro -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata

-country-japan
-city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Toyota Motor -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Mitsubishi UFJ Financial -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Softbank -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Nippon Telegraph & Tel -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for nam in -country-france -country-india -country-japan; do cont=$(sed -n "/$nam/{n;p}"  gh.txt) ;echo $nam;sed -n "/$nam/{n;p}"  gh.txt;for linnum in $(awk -v nam="$nam" '$0 ~ nam,/^$/{print NR}' gh.txt |sed -e '1,2d' -e '/^$/d'); do awk -v linnum="$linnum" -v cont="$cont" 'NR==linnum {print $0,cont}' gh.txt|sed "/^ $cont/d";done;done
```

output

```
-country-france
-city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-TotalEnergies -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-AXA -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Carrefour -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Crédit Agricole -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-Peugeot -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-business-BNP Paribas -city-Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse, Nice, Nantes
-country-india
-city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Reliance Industries Limited -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-State Bank of India -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-HDFC Bank -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-ICICI Bank -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Tata Consultancy Services -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-business-Larsen & Toubro -city-New Delhi, Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai, Kolkata
-country-japan
-city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Toyota Motor -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Mitsubishi UFJ Financial -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Softbank -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
-business-Nippon Telegraph & Tel -city-Tokyo, Yokohama, Osaka, Nagoya, Sapporo, Fukuoka, Kobe
```